# openCV python is not reading my images, path does not exist

Tags: python, string, opencv

I have a text file containing several images paths, suppose it is called DATA.TXT and the format is as follows:

```
Dataset_Eyes_Digital/RAW_Split/01401.png
Dataset_Eyes_Digital/RAW_Split/13349.png
Dataset_Eyes_Digital/RAW_Split/00134.png
...
```

However, these are not the real paths of the images. I have to add some strings to these paths when I read the text file line by line to get the absolute and real path of each image file, like as follows:

```
 file1="DATA.TXT"
 Lines = file1.readlines() 

 for line in Lines:
    
        indices_name=line.split('/')
        right_eye_path="/home/me/Desktop/"+indices_name[0]+"/"+indices_name[1]+"/Right/"+"right_"+indices_name[2]
        left_eye_path="/home/me/Desktop/"+indices_name[0]+"/"+indices_name[1]+"/Left/"+"left_"+indices_name[2]
```

For example, the entry **Dataset_Eyes_Digital/RAW_Split/01401.png** in that text file would give me the following two image files:

```
 right_eye_path=/home/me/Desktop/Dataset_Eyes_Digital/RAW_Split/Right/right_01401.png
 left_eye_path=/home/me/Desktop/Dataset_Eyes_Digital/RAW_Split/Left/left_01401.png
```

Then, I just needed to read the files with opencv imread

```
 left_eye_img = cv2.imread(left_eye_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
 right_eye_img = cv2.imread(right_eye_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

My problem is: whenever I run and read the file paths with OpenCV, it returns me a NoneType. When I ask if the file exists, it says me it does not.

```
>> print(right_eye_img)
>> None
>> print(os.path.exists(right_eye_path)) 
>> False
```

However, if I open a python terminal and copy and paste the image path, it reads correctly. It also says to me that the image path exists, so **probably the problem is the way I am treating the string variables in my code.** How can I solve such an issue?

Comment: can you also do: print(right_eye_path) ?

Comment: @voyager42 when I print, the correct name appears. If I copy and paste to the Python terminal, it works. The problem is now solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also do a `.strip()` when you get lines from a file, since they contain a new line character at the end `\n`

Like so:

```
import os

file1 = "DATA.TXT"
f = open(file1, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    indices_name = line.strip().split('/')
    right_eye_path = "/home/me/Desktop/" + indices_name[0] + "/" + indices_name[1] + "/Right/" + "right_" + indices_name[2]
    left_eye_path = "/home/me/Desktop/" + indices_name[0] + "/" + indices_name[1] + "/Left/" + "left_" + indices_name[2]
    print(right_eye_path)
    print(left_eye_path)
    print(os.path.exists(right_eye_path))
    print(os.path.exists(left_eye_path))
```